# Find all integral coordinates given top left corner and bottom right corner of a rectangle

Tags: python, performance, algorithm

Here is the problem I am working on -

> There is an \$N \times N\$ field on which missiles are being bombarded. Initially,
>   all the cells in this field have the value \$0\$. There will be \$M\$ missiles
>   bombarded on this field. The \$i\$th missile will have power \$P_i\$ and it will
>   affect all the cells in region with \$(A_i,B_i)\$ as top-left corner and
>   \$(C_i,D_i)\$ as bottom-right corner. Because of missile, value of all the
>   cells in this rectangle will get `XOR`ed with \$P_i\$.
>
> After all the missiles have been bombarded, you have to find out
>   values in each cell of this field.

Here is what I have tried -

```
N = 3
M = 3
missiles = [[3,3,1,3,2],
[2,2,1,2,2],
[3,1,1,2,3]]

from itertools import product
# Logic
coords = {}
for i in missiles:
    Pi, Ai, Bi, Ci, Di = i
    for j in product(*[range(Ai-1, Ci), range(Bi-1, Di)]):
        if coords.get(j):
            coords[j] ^= Pi
            #[NxN[i[0]][i[1]] ^= Pi
        else:
            coords[j] = 0 ^ Pi

def print_grid(coords, N):
    count = 0
    for i in product(*[range(N), range(N)]):
        if i in coords:
            print(coords[i], "",end="")
        else:
            print(0, "",end="")
        count+=1
        if count%N==0:
            print()

print_grid(coords, N)
```

Output -

```
3 3 3 
1 1 3 
3 3 0
```

Exactly does what I want, but I was wondering is there a way to optimize it for large inputs. Any help appreciated.

Comment: (Welcome to CR!) (I don't post without the help of a spelling checker.) How would you design based on *symbolic execution* of effects? Can the solution be produced by a [systolic array](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systolic_array) or more than one thread? Can a symbolic representation of `N x N` be found and presented strictly faster than in `N x N` steps?

Comment: @greybeard multithreading might be a good option. I, however want to question my logic, whether it is the most optimized logic, not concerned about the implementation right now.

Comment: Is an approach using `numpy` any good for you?

Comment: @MathiasEttinger yes very much. So lets say I make an `np.array()` out of the coordinate indices and find a way to multiply `Pi` directly with the original `np.zeros((N,N))` that would help. The bottleneck for me seems to be the way I am generating all the points in the rectangle given `Ai, Bi, Ci, Di`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since you commented that using `numpy` is OK for you, you can simplify the whole rectangle computation using its advanced slicing capabilities:

```
>>> # Let's define a square array
... 
>>> a = np.array(range(25)).reshape((5, 5))
>>> a
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
       [15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
       [20, 21, 22, 23, 24]])
>>> # Advanced slicing allow us to extract blocks at once
... 
>>> a[2:5, 1:3]
array([[11, 12],
       [16, 17],
       [21, 22]])
```

You just need to encapsulate this behaviour in a class for ease of use:

```
import numpy as np


class BattleField:
    def __init__(self, size):
        self.field = np.zeros((size, size), dtype=int)

    def receive_missile(self, power, top, left, bottom, right):
        self.field[top-1:bottom, left-1:right] ^= power

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.field)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    missiles = [
        [3,3,1,3,2],
        [2,2,1,2,2],
        [3,1,1,2,3],
    ]
    field = BattleField(3)
    for missile in missiles:
        field.receive_missile(*missile)
    print(field)
```

---

Other points to improve from your code includes:

- using more descriptive names than `A`, `B`, or `C`;
- using functions instead of code at top-level for ease of testing/reuse;
- using the [`if __name__ == '__main__'`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do) guard to avoid running some code when importing the file;
- using direct parameters values instead of packing them in a list and unpacking them in the function call (`product(*[range(N), range(N)])` => `product(range(N), range(N))`);
- using `dict.get` with its default value (`coords[j] = coords.get(j, 0) ^ Pi`) to simplify the code.

Comment: Thanks @MathiasEttinger this is elegant. I timed it against mine - 
`10.6 µs ± 3.01 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each) # for mine` and `31.3 µs ± 10.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)` on yours. You think this is because of the overhead of loading numpy in such a small example?

Comment: @VivekKalyanarangan If you time the whole script, that's possible. You can make a function out of the testing code and only time the function, to figure it out.

Comment: Cool that works. This definitely gives me a lot to think about. Glad to accept! :-)